# How does Eclipse Marketplace's drag to install work?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-marketplace, update-site

How does Eclipse get all the metadata, e.g., update sites to add to the update site list, from the url [http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=[plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=%5Bplugin) ID] ?

Comment: The metadata is requested via the API provided by https://marketplace.eclipse.org - The code of the [Eclipse Marketplace Client](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.packaging.mpc) can be found [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/mpc/org.eclipse.epp.mpc.git/log/).

Comment: @howlger So what is the essential API URL behind the scene? Definitely I crave for it to optimize the download experience in consideration of the network conditions me here. Once I thought the metadata is in the web page but I failed to locate.

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Marketplace/REST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the REST API used by the [Eclipse Marketplace Client](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.packaging.mpc) can be found in the Eclipse Wiki here:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Marketplace/REST